# How do I limit access to only a single domain on my child's account?

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls

How do I set up my child's account to be able to only access one domain on the Internet, and no other site?

Comment: I'm sorry but I just gotta say it: that is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for [Parenting.SE](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I answered below, but I do want to chime in that this seems like an incredibly stupid thing to do.  At least let her also use Wikipedia, or CNN, or anything she can actually develop her brain with.

Comment: Okay, this is a really really bad idea, but let's focus on the technical part, shall we?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Family Safety ([Setup Instructions Here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-up-family-safety#set-up-family-safety=windows-7)) has this capability.  It is part of the free Windows Essentials package.  [Download Here.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/essentials-other#essentials=overviewother)

I no longer have a Win7 machine to test this out, but on Win8, you can set up a whitelist in [the online control panel](https://familysafety.microsoft.com).  Note you need a free Microsoft account to do this.

1. Go to `web filtering` on the left side menu
2. Turn filtering on with slider at top of page.
3. Move slider to `allow list only`
4. Click `allow list` link in slider.
5. Enter `facebook.com` into the field that appears and click `allow`

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best idea, and maybe end up backfiring!

You should take an approach to software that is actually designed for protecting children on the internet rather than blocking everything! We use this software at my agency for our guest network and seems to work very well, and very customize-able. Seems like the same filter any school might use.

http://www1.k9webprotection.com/